# C/C++ Compiler Optimization regarding Variable Scope

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-optimization

I'm not sure about the source, but my current knowledge is that the local variables of a C/C++ function are initialized at the entry to the function. But I also can read that declaring variables as close as possible to its use will help the compiler optimize the code. I am quite confused with these two conflicting arguments.

ps.
I am asking about how the machine deals with code, not for humans.

edit:
To clarify my question, if all the local variables of a function are initialized at the entry to the function, than declaring variables in the middle of the function body will have no other benefits than better readability. However, I have also read that variables declared close to its use helps the compiler to optimize. And it is hard for me to understand how these two conflicting arguments can go together. Any explanation will help.

Comment: In C++ local variables are initialized at the point of declaration. Regardless of any optimizations it's generally preferred to declare them at a point closest to their first use, no reason to declare them earlier than they aren't used.

Comment: Try and cite your sources. Also, C/C++ is not a language.

Comment: @Jonathon C/C++ = C and/or C++. If there is any significant difference between the two languages concerning my question, then any answer can explain.

Comment: @CaptainOblivious only if they actually have an initializer (or a constructor) of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, if you declared closest to the usage, there's a chance that the variable won't be constructed at all if that scope is not hit.

```
class SomeHeavyObjectToConstruct { //...};
```

Version 1:

```
SomeHeavyObjectToConstruct obj1;
if (some_condition) {
  // do something with obj1
} else {
  // won't touch obj1
}
```

Version 2:

```
if (some_condition) {
  SomeHeavyObjectToConstruct obj1;
  // do something with obj1
} else {
  // won't touch obj1
}
```

In this way, Version 2 performs better than Version 1

Comment: something from tbb document: "...uses local temporary variables for scalar values accessed inside the loop. This technique can improve
performance by making it obvious to the compiler that the values can be held in registers instead of memory"

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked with true cases but my understanding of compiler optimization tells me that:

- the compiler is smart enough to trace data dependencies and tell when a variable is needed;
- automatic variables will not be initialized upon entering the function but later, when needed;
- the place where a variable declaration is put in the source code will have no impact.